# How is the error passed to next in catch(next)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I often see something like this

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Promise.resolve().then(function () {
    throw new Error('BROKEN')
  }).catch(next)
})
```

And I can't understand how the line `catch(next)` works. How does it pass the error from `catch` to `next()`? Could someone explain this to me? Or tell me what to google because I can't find anything about this feature myself.Thanks in advance!

Comment: @CherryDT like higher order function?

Comment: yes, exactly. (although I don't think of it like that, in JavaScript functions are no different from any other sort of value like a number or an array - they can be passed around, have properties, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code internal to the `catch` function calls the callback that it received as its argument (in your case `next`) with the error as argument.

You can build something similar and try it yourself:

```js
function myCatch (callback) {
  const e = new Error('oh no')
  callback(e)
}

function next (error) {
  console.log('got error:', error) 
}

myCatch(next)
// Result is: you get `got error: Error: oh no`
```

If I have a `function a () {}` and I do `const b = a` (not `const b = a()`!) I can write `b()` afterwards and essentially call `a` this way. and the same happens here too, but as argument to another function (the `catch` method). You are already doing this with `then` - you are passing an (anonymous, in this case) function as argument, which `then` will later call for you. And think about it - your whole request handler does this too - the `next` you receive as argument to your handler function is also a function that is passed in by Express to your function! Instead of calling it yourself, you can also pass it on to another function, etc.